# does a blocking network call within Django block all threads?

Tags: windows, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm running Django servers under Apache/Mod_WSGI on Windows.  As part of processing my user requests, I do a lot of things that require network I/O.  I run queries through the Django ORM (to a database server on another machine).  I also make non-Django ODBC queries, I read files and directories on network shares, and I scrape other websites.

I'm pretty sure that at least some of my network I/O is blocking (the ODBC queries and the web scraping leap to mind).  And Apache on Windows only has a threaded processing model, not a multi-process model.

So my first question is: If I make a blocking networking call while responding to a request, does that block all the threads within the Apache server, or just the thread that's responding to the request?

And my second question is:  are any of these four kinds of network calls (Django ORM, ODBC, network share, HTTP) known to be non-blocking?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, it should not block other request threads. This though is dependent on the C code underlying stuff releasing the Python GIL around blocking calls. All Python code wrappers around system network and file system functions will do this correctly. You should also be fine for mainstream database adapters as they would also know to release the GIL as necessary. The problem of blocking only usually comes up with naively written third party C extension modules where people know no better but that is quite rare these days.